# print result from all devices on array

Tags: perl

I just write this script however the script only print one result not the results from all devices. I belive my error is on print section but I couldn't figure out.

Note :- the host file has 30 devices list but the script print the result of the last device only.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$host_file  = "/usr/local/bin/test/host2";

open (PACKETLOSS,"$host_file") or die "Cannot Open Extracted host file";

# Put Extracted data into an array

@extracted_array=<PACKETLOSS>;

chomp(@extracted_array);

foreach(@extracted_array) {
    @words = split;
    $host = $words[0];
}

$extracted_array[$ping_idx] = `/usr/sbin/ping -s -t 10 $host 56 2 2>&1`; 

$ping_idx++;

($packet_loss) = ($ping =~ m/packets received, (\d+)% packet loss/);

($round_trip) = ($ping =~ m/round-trip.*\(ms\).*min\/avg\/max\/stddev = \d+\.\d+\/(\d+\.\d+)\/.*/);

print " $host $round_trip ms Average Latency and $packet_loss Packet loss\n";
```

Comment: It would be easier to read if you made the code appear as code by offsetting each line four spaces from the left. That would help much. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause you are closing foreach and then performing the operation. IT should be

```
foreach(@extracted_array) 
 {
   @words = split; 
  $host = $words[0]; 
  $extracted_array[$ping_idx] = `/usr/sbin/ping -s -t 10 $host 56 2 2>&1`; 
  $ping_idx++; 
 ($packet_loss) = ($ping =~ m/packets received, (\d+)% packet loss/);  
 ($round_trip) = ($ping =~ m/round-trip.*\(ms\).*min\/avg\/max\/stddev = \d+\.\d+\/(\d+\.\d+)\/.*/); 
  print " $host $round_trip ms Average Latency and $packet_loss Packet loss\n";  
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your foreach loop close at the very bottom of the code.

```
foreach(@extracted_array) {
    @words = split;
    $host = $words[0];

    $extracted_array[$ping_idx] = `/usr/sbin/ping -s -t 10 $host 56 2 2>&1`; 

    $ping_idx++;

    ($packet_loss) = ($ping =~ m/packets received, (\d+)% packet loss/);

    ($round_trip) = ($ping =~ m/round-trip.*\(ms\).*min\/avg\/max\/stddev = \d+\.\d+\/(\d+\.\d+)\/.*/);

    print " $host $round_trip ms Average Latency and $packet_loss Packet loss\n"; 

}
```